# SQL echo table row error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm VERY new to SQL, I have a table called "accounts". I want to echo all account info on an HTML table, I've tried this but it didn't work? (There are the proper tags around the php code)

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM acccounts";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

Comment: sql-server <> mysql

Comment: ? I don't understand

Comment: As simple no `<table>` was defined ...

Comment: +Abdulla Nilam I have `<table>` tags around this PHP code

Comment: Couple things.. #1 mysql functions in PHP are depreciated and you should be using mysqlI (thats a letter eye at the end) #2 You need to connect to the database before fetching data from it   *ps in addition to MySQLI there is also PDO

Comment: you had used sql-server as tag, but you should know that this is a mysql question. sql-server is referred to Microsoft SQL Server. if you specify incorrect tag, people who are not interested on that topic will see you question.

Comment: i use sqlsrv, its nice and easy to use, either way mysql is deprecated, if you wanna use it, use mysqli, its the new version.  -  edit: sorry didnt see @duane Lortlie's comment,

Comment: we don't know if you did successfully connect using the same `mysql_` api here. The only way for me to test your code (which I think looks ok), would be to test it using either the mysqli_ or PDO api.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam *"As simple no `<table>` was defined"* - Even still, they should still get results and viewable in HTML source, as a worse case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is pretty obvious; you either didn't connect to your database, or your system doesn't allow the use of the `mysql_` API.

Or, you tried connecting with the `mysqli_` or other API (which is unknown). If this is the case; those different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

Using the `mysqli_` API on my own machine produced results:

Replace the following with your own credentials:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$connect = mysqli_connect("your_host", "user", "pass", "db");
if (!$connect) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$query="SELECT * FROM acccounts";
$results = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if($results){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
}
else{
    echo "Your query failed: " . mysqli_error($connect);

    }
```

Check for errors on the query and via PHP.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

**Note:** Even without the `<table></table>` tags, it will still produce results, on a successful query.

- Plus, this requires the file to be executed using a webserver with php/mysql installed and used as `http://localhost` as opposed to `file:///`, should this be the case.

Other reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Few things, First off, you need to connect to the database with the sql instance name, uid and passwd strings, 
secondly 
your query should be `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`

ie

```
$servername = 'yourinstance\sqlexpress';
$conndetails = ["Database" => "databasename", "UID" => 'loginid', "PWD" =>'passwd'];
$sqlconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $conndetails);
$query = "Select blah blah";
$query2 = mysqli_query($sqlconn, $query);
```

double check the syntax because i often get it backwards off the mark but without this setup you can't connect to the database,
PHP has to authenticate / login before it can make queries (otherwise anyone would be able to query your database)

Additional to this, you need to ensure sql is listening on the right ports (normally 1433) this is done through the sql manager (not the sql explorer).

the results are still in array format, so you need to call the specific field name.
in this case.

```
echo '<td>' . $field['id'] . '</td>';
```

should work, (this is the format i use)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' .$field['id']. '</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing appears but page keeps repeatedly loading?

Comment: see edit re: connecting to the sql instance.

ill throw more detail in in a moment.,

Comment: why are you suggesting they use mysqli_ to connect and query with, then including `mysql_fetch_array()` afterwards? Those different APIs don't intermix.

Comment: cause i started off just modifying his string then changing it around, see fresh edit @fred -ii- , 

i do a short answer then always rethink it and start editing lol.

Comment: @CraigB Up until that we/I get clarification from a few comments left under their question, is anybody's ballgame really.

Comment: agreed, without knowing IF he had connection strings there, but i know that without the connection in the query line it wouldnt have worked 
`$results = mysql_query($query);` needed to be `$results = mysql_query($connectionstring,$query);`